# Set User Who Started Build

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a bot that executes build via a curl call to .. http://admin:1234@jenkins-api.com/job/Some_Job/build

The problem is that sets the user who kicked off the build as the admin. I would like to be able to set the user who kicked off the build to the correct user. I already have their credentials stored I just need a way to make jenkins update the "Started by user" field. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you know who is starting the build, and you have their API token, why can't you just use their details in the curl call?

Comment: How do I get the api token? I have their details (meaning just their login) but the credentials I have been using to post are the admins

Comment: I assumed that "I already have their credentials stored" meant that you somehow had the user-API token (or user-password) pair (i.e. their credentials) stored for each user. API token is shown on each user's Configure page.

Comment: is there a way to grab the user-API token from jenkins api?